# http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php “Says site can’t be reached”. Apache fail to start

Tags: apache-http-server, php, localhost

I am using Antergos.

I have installed a lampp stack with `PHP 7.2.8`, for the last couple of days my `apache` has been not starting, when I check httpd status I get(screenshot below) 
*Click to see the image*

[image: Apache failure Image]

Also `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` "Says site can’t be reached"

[image: Localhost cannot be reached image]

Comment: Your httpd.conf has an error you apache is not started resolve or replace the conf file.

Comment: How do I replace conf file @AbhishekGurjar? ~ newbie

Answer (score 0):

Your `libphp7` module seems to be missing or inaccessible. Not too familiar with Antergos but have a look under `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules` or `/etc/https/modules` or just try to use `locate libphp7` to see if it's even there. You may need to install `php-apache` package if it's not present.